# Cannot update global angular/cli from 11 to 12

Tags: angular-cli

Running in Windows 10 with:

- Node v14.17.0
- NPM v6.14.13

I had Angular/CLI 11.0.1 installed globally. I'm stuck trying to upgrade it to v12, but no matter what I do, ng --version returns Angular CLI: 11.0.1.

I've tried:

- uninstalling
- npm cache verify
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
- npm install -g @angular/cli@12.1.3

These all run ok, with no errors.

However,  ng --version still returns Angular CLI: 11.0.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't get to the cause of the problem.
However, I did fix it by uninstalling Node and clearing the node directory. Then reinstalling Node and Angular from scratch. A bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`

To get to know about Angular 11.0 -> 12.0, refer this update guide:

https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-12.0

Comment: That's for updating a project, to Angular 12, not the actual installed global version of Angular.